# OhMyZSH plugins do not function: command not found

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

Setting up a new laptop. Installed iTerm2, zsh, and OhMyZSH.

.zshrc looks like:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
#export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

plugins=(git ripgrep web-search)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
```

I get confirmation that the plugin is enabled:

```
➜  ~ omz plugin enable ripgrep
omz::plugin::enable: plugin 'ripgrep' is already enabled.
```

But when I try to use it (or any other plugin)

```
➜  ~ rg
zsh: command not found: rg
➜  ~ ripgrep
zsh: command not found: ripgrep
```

Comment: Since the question is basically about configuration and use of oh-my-zsh, I suggest that you post this at [su].